# RequestAnimationFrame FPS varing with window size

Tags: javascript, canvas, requestanimationframe

I have a Canvas which resizes to fill the whole window automatically when the window is resized.

In one corner of the canvas I am drawing 5 animated sprites. No problem here.

This runs at a perfect 60 fps but when I maximize the window to fill the screen the fps drops to 30 fps and fluctuates between 30 fps and 60 fps. When I make the window smaller again it goes back to a consistent 60 fps.

All the animation is just in one corner of the canvas the rest of the canvas is blank. I understand it is very inefficient to redraw the whole canvas on every tick, and should only redraw the part that is changing.

But my question is - is this normal behaviour? Should redrawing the whole screen, even though the screen is blank apart from a few sprites in the corner, cause the fps to fluctuate between 30 and 60 fps?

Browser: Chrome 20
OS: OSX Lion
Computer: Macbook Air

I have included a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XQpzU/3561/

Try making the rendering window bigger and the FPS will drop.

Comment: Performance depends a lot of things so maybe that is not that anormal. What happens if you try to [clip](http://www.w3.org/TR/2dcontext/#clipping-region) ?

Comment: Clipping results in 60fps. I'm just suprised Canvas2D is not better optimized.